# Struts2 RedirectAction: Params Interceptor and Workflow?

Tags: redirect, struts2, action, parameters

My common usecase for my Struts2 application is that I have Actions that collect data which are presented on an JSP page. I'll call these view-actions.

But then I also have logic actions, which "do" something in the background (like registering a user). These might also have a bean that needs to be shown on an JSP, but I need to redirect the result to one of the view-actions.

Sadly, the bean I need from the first action doesn't get transferred to the ValueStack, but only values from getters from the view action. Example:

```
<action name="mailConfirm" class="de.abelssoft.updateyeti.Frontend.MailConfirmer">
  <result name="login" type="redirectAction">
    <param name="actionName">register</param>
    <param name="email">${person.email}</param>
  </result>
  <result name="input" type="redirectAction">
    <param name="actionName">register</param>
  </result>
</action>
```

What is the pattern I'm missing here? Or do I have to store everything I need in the response context?

Comment: That's not very clear. What do you mean by "an action that does something in the background"? An action executes some logic in response to a web request, always. Could you elaborate your scenario, or give an example?

Comment: Example: a user submits a comment in a form to the action submitComment. The URL called is "submitComment.action?comment=thisisacomment". A field in the submitComment action is set with the comment's string so the message "Your comment 'thisisacomment' was added". 

Another example would be the above "registerUser.action?email=example@example.com". A database error occurs and the user should be informed about this.

The result of these action are other actions that render the viewed JSP. I want the messages / objects from the first action to be availble to the second action.

Comment: Sorry. Your examples do not clarify much, for me at least. "The result of these action are other actions that render the viewed JSP" - normally you dont have an action dedicated to show results, that goes against MVC. The results (99% of time) are shown in a JSP that reads data from the executed action. The result type="redirectAction" should be rare in a Struts2 app. I recomend Mannings' "Struts2 in Action"

Comment: Thanks for your response. Often times, the result of a Struts2 Action is a JSP, like if you want to show data from a DB. But if an action is not collecting data for a view but triggers a logical action (like adding the users' email to a DB), you might want to redirect the user to a view-rendering action. Like this:

<action name="search" class="example.Search">
  <result name="success">/list.jsp</result>
  <result name="redirect" type="redirectAction">
    <param name="actionName">info</param>
    <param name="detailsId">${sid}</param>
  </result>
</action>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got no answer to this question, so I'll tell you what I've done. Sorry for not providing a "good answer".

I wrote two interceptors. One for the logical action that would store message-objects in the user session temporarily and one for my view actions that would take and remove them out of the usersession.

I used the logical action interceptor where needed and used the viewaction interceptor for all other action to make sure that when an action redirection has happened before the view action, the message-objects will be found and used.